# How to get month difference in jquery having only months and years

Tags: jquery

How to get the month difference in jquery while my input contains just months and years, but  not day? My input is from :(4-2011) To :(5-2015) .

Comment: Hoe, haha. :D I am afraid you have to be a bit more specific in your question. You want to calculate months from one date to another, but in one of the inputs, you only record month and year? You could count whole months? Months as a decimal? Again, be more specific.

Comment: @OptimusCrime i think he means that he just want to know how many months there are between those two dates. It seems clear to me.

Comment: my input is from drop down just month and year as from month to end month of tow different years for payment of joomal (Jom Social)

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
var a = "1-2014";
var b = "4-2015";
a = a.split('-');
b = b.split('-');
months = (b[1]-a[1]) * 12 + (b[0]-a[0]);
alert(months);
```

Comment: @irfan if this answers your question you should accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your strings with JavaScript using the two functions below. I have seperated them in case you need to calculate the number of months between two `DateTime` values in the future.

## Usage

```
var monthDiffVal = monthDiffFromString("4-2011", "5-2015");
```

## Functions

```
// This function takes your two string dates, converts them into DateTimes
// and passes them to the monthDiff function below

function monthDiffFromString(s1, s2) {
    var startString = s1;  //4-2011;
    var endString = s2; //5-2015;
    var startStringArr = endString.split('-');
    var endStringArr = endString.split('-');

    var startDate = new DateTime(startStringArr[1], startStringArr[0], 01);
    var endDate = new DateTime(endStringArr[1], endStringArr[0], 01);

    return monthDiff(date1, date2); //pass your dates to the function above
}

// This function calculates the number of months between two dates

function monthDiff(date1, date2) { 
    var m; 
    m = (date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear()) * 12; 
    m -= date1.getMonth() + 1; 
    m += date2.getMonth(); 
    return m; 
}
```

Comment: He doesn't have full dates and you should provide a full answer not just a hint, this belongs more to a comment.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Date(2011, 4),
    b = new Date(2015, 5),

    months = (b-a)/2628000000;
```